# .htaccess redirect to URL when match on certain file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Under my root web directory, I have this two files:

**aboutus.php**

**about-us.php**

Now going to this URL http://local.com/about-us.php will render the file **about-us.php**. If I will do the inverse, how can I dictate the .htaccess that whenever the URL above is access, the **aboutus.php** will be rendered?

Comment: The whole idea is silly. You want to avoid `.php` altogether. Study up on SEF/SEO urls. To get started, route all requests to one `index.php` file and have that php file sort out what will handle the output.

Comment: Even I find it silly, but what can I do, if that is what they want.

Comment: They want awful urls? I find that highly suspect. Have you communicated to "them" about the importance of search engine optimization and user experience?

Comment: @m59: ever worked with people how thought they knew what they need? YOu can have a pretty hard time to convince them that they don't - and you don't eveng et payed for that. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the whole server config, the most efficient way to do this is to use `mod_alias`. Unfortunately this needs to be done in `VirtualHost` config - which is only accessible if you got root access to that server.

```
Alias /about-us.php /full/local/path/to/aboutus.php
```

If you cannot edit the VirtualHost config, use `mod_rewrite` (needs more server resources though, as every request has to be matched to those rules):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^about-us.php aboutus.php [L]
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Oh. Wait. Screw that. `Alias` is only allowed in global and VirtualHost context, not in .htaccess. DO you have access to the whole server config? Otherwiese we'll ahve to use mod_rewrite.

Comment: Either or, but for now .htaccess is the preferred way.

Comment: Toggeling the rewrite_engine on eats a lot of ressources, so I'd avoiud it if you can (at least if you have lots of traffic). mod_alias is less expensive resource wise. That's why I suggested it in the first palce.